# prevent JQuery datepicker reset after onSelect event

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I don't know what is this called, I think something like reset..

The case is like this:
I'm using inline datepicker and then I add a new Class that have own style (css) to some date in datepicker. Below is the code:

```
$("#calendar").datepicker({ 
                            showOtherMonths: true, 
                            onSelect:function(){
                                                alert($(this).val());
                                                }
                            });
$(document).ready(function(){
    customDate();
});                         
function customDate(){
    $("#calendar a:eq(10)").addClass("has_event");
}
```

code above will add new class at 10th index 'a' element, and style for that class is:

```
.has_event{
    color:#bb0000 !important;
    font-weight:bold !important;
    background:#cccccc !important;
}
```

The customDate() function work well at first, but after the datepicker selected, the style is reseted to default because the new Class added is gone.

So anyone knows how to prevent the datepicker reset after selected or even after onSelect event?

@S.M.09 this is what I've done :

```
_selectDay:function(id,month,year,td){var target=$(id);if($(td).hasClass(this._unselectableClass)||this._isDisabledDatepicker(target[0])){return}var inst=this._getInst(target[0]);inst.selectedDay=inst.currentDay=$("a",td).html();inst.selectedMonth=inst.currentMonth=month;inst.selectedYear=inst.currentYear=year;if(inst.stayOpen){inst.endDay=inst.endMonth=inst.endYear=null}this._selectDate(id,this._formatDate(inst,inst.currentDay,inst.currentMonth,inst.currentYear));if(inst.stayOpen){inst.rangeStart=this._daylightSavingAdjust(new Date(inst.currentYear,inst.currentMonth,inst.currentDay));this._updateDatepicker(inst)} if(id=="#calendar"){$("#calendar a:eq(10)").addClass("has_event");}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of you generally want some days to be styled differently you can put them in an array (*to be persistent and dynamic*)

```
var myDates = [9,13];
```

and use the [`beforeShowDay` <sup>docs</sup>](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-beforeShowDay) event to check each day rendered with your array

```
 beforeShowDay:function(date) {
                      var thisDay = date.getDate();

                      return [1,((myDates.indexOf(thisDay))>-1)?'has_event':''];
                    }
```

this applies to the `td` so you need to change your css to `.has_event a{..`

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/dTRNf/

Answer (score 0):

In the jQuery js(jquery-ui-x.x.x.custom.min.js)...you will find a function with four arguments(the variable names can be different depending on the version) called

```
_selectDay:function(a,b,c,d)
```

add the code just before the end of the function

```
if(a=="#calendar"){
$("#calendar a:eq(10)").addClass("has_event");
}
```

remove the `if condition` if you want it globally...the code above will apply it only to the calendar you want

**EDIT**

```
_selectDay:function(a,b,c,e){
    var f=d(a);
    if(!(d(e).hasClass(this._unselectableClass)||this._isDisabledDatepicker(f[0]))){
        f=this._getInst(f[0]);
        f.selectedDay=f.currentDay=d("a",e).html();
        f.selectedMonth=f.currentMonth=b;
        f.selectedYear=f.currentYear=c;
        this._selectDate(a,this._formatDate(f,f.currentDay,f.currentMonth,f.currentYear))
        }
    if(a=="#calendar"){
    $("#calendar a:eq(10)").addClass("has_event");
    }


},
```

Comment: I've tried as you say, 
I was found the function that have four arguments and I have add the code
$("#calendar a:eq(10)").addClass("has_event"); before the end of that function (with if condition and also without)
but the datepicker is still reset after selected.
is there any solution for this?

Comment: not before the function you need to add it at the end of the function...I said.. **just before the end of the function**..look at the edit

Comment: pls edit your post and show me what you did...also try putting an alert inside the if to check if the control comes there...

Comment: of course, i add the code before the end of that function (inside the function).
but the datepicker still reseted